# PHP with Curl -- Can I pass another key and value to one of the form fields?

Tags: php, forms, curl

So my HTTP form post is failing because it's missing a few key items. For example, here's what it's sending:

```
--------------------------9960f1a56d650126
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test_id"

343
--------------------------9960f1a56d650126
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo
```

And here's what I need to post

```
--10AE0BB3-605D-4F10-A3C1-D2A18DCB82B9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test_id"

343
--10AE0BB3-605D-4F10-A3C1-D2A18DCB82B9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="photo"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

It's the `filename="photo"`, Content-type, and content-transfer-encoding fields that are being passed with that particular area of the form (I guess those are form paremeters? Not sure).

Here's what my PHP code looks like:

```
if($post) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
```

Data gets created like this:

```
function BuildData($file_name) {
    if(!$file_name) {
        echo "The image doesn't exist ".$file_name;
    } else {
        $data = [
            'test_id' => time(), 
            'photo' => file_get_contents($file_name),
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

So I guess I need to somehow figure out a way to add those required parameters like the filename="photo" and the other two form field headers (not sure what the proper term is).

I've tried to add a few things like:

```
photo=file_get_contents($file_name) . ';filename="photo";
```

and append on to that, but that doesn't work. It still gets included in the actual raw image data and not as a separate header or whatever.

Any suggestions?